# Separador de miles en campo input tipo number (ANGULAR)

Tags: angular, typescript, input

Muy buenas, gente. Antes que nada, gracias por adelantado a los que me ayudéis (y a los que no también).

Veréis, tengo un campo input tipo `number` en el que quiero que aparezca el punto que separa los miles y así hacerlo mas legible. He visto que usando `mask="separator.2" thousandSeparator="."` en un tipo `text` sale, pero el problema que tengo con eso es que no funcionan los `Validators`, supongo que porque le llega como un string en vez de como un numero.

¿Alguien sabe como podría solucionarlo? Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es implementar una directiva que implemente un `ControlValueAccessor` que muestre los datos "localizados" pero que se le pase a los validators en el formato estándar de Typescript (sin separador de miles y usando el punto como separador de decimales)

Answer (score 1):

> Para separar los valores en un input y validarlos en un Formulario
> Reactivo podemos utilizar

[DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)

> Conjuntamente con Pipes personalizados
> **number.pipe.ts**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'tonumber'
})
export class NumberPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string):any {
    let retNumber = Number(value);
    return isNaN(retNumber) ? 0 : retNumber;
}

}
```

> Custom Validator **validator.ts** nos permite trabajar con decimales

```js
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export class NumberValidators {

  static isNumberCheck(): ValidatorFn {
    return  (c: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} | null => {
      let number = /^[.\d]+$/.test(c.value) ? +c.value : NaN;
      if (number !== number) {
        return { 'value': true };
      }

      return null;
    };
  }
}
```

> Registramos en app.module.ts

```js
import { LOCALE_ID, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DecimalPipe } from './decimal.pipe';
import localeEsAr from '@angular/common/locales/es-AR';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import { NumberPipe } from './number.pipe';
registerLocaleData(localeEsAr, 'es-Ar');


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DecimalPipe,
    NumberPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [ { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'es-Ar' } ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> En  app.component.ts y app.component.html

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { NumberValidators } from './validator';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
form!: FormGroup ;
constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {}
 ngOnInit(): void {
 
 this.form = this.fb.group({
      number: ['',[
        NumberValidators.isNumberCheck()]]
    })
 }
  get number(){ return this.form.get('number'); }
 doSome(form: FormGroup){
    console.log('Valid?', form.valid); 
    
  }
 }
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (onSubmit)="doSome(form)">
  <input type="text" formControlName="number" id="number" required>
  <p>{{form.get('number')!.value | tonumber|number: '1.0-9':'es-AR'}}</p>

  <div *ngIf="number!.invalid && (number!.dirty || number!.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">

    <div *ngIf="number!.errors?.['required']">
      number is required.
    </div>
  </div>

  <button [disabled]="form.invalid" type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

> Si son valores decimales se ingresan con notacion de punto de acuerdo
> al Pipe Decimal de Angular y se mostraran segun la localidad en este
> caso Argentina
> Si se ingresa por ejemplo `12478956.265` se muestra como..>`12.478.956,265`